# Downloading a PDF in chrome intermittently tries to save page instead of PDF

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf

I'm outputting a PDF via PHP with the following code. `$file` is an object that contains data pertaining to the file being displayed.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$file->name.'"');
@readfile($file->ServerPath());
```

My issue is that when I go to download the file in Chrome it will occasionally try to save the page instead of the PDF.

For example, say the URL that is displaying the file is mywebsite.com/file?file_id=1234. Most of the time it will try to save the file correctly as "file_name.pdf". However, sometimes chrome will try to save the file as "file" with no extension. This seems to happen randomly.

If it makes any difference the page displaying the file is being opened in a new tab. The issue happens regardless of whether I redirect via PHP or Javascript.

I really need to resolve this issue, as these PDFs will be accessible by users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What web-server service are you running? Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc? What are the caching rules? Have you tried setting the appropriate HTTP headers for the browser cache as shown in the [`readfile` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)?

Comment: @fyrye Oh, good call! I'm using Apache. I'll have to double check my caching rules tomorrow. I'll let you know if that works!